# How to associate existsing users from django.contrib.auth with Python Social Auth (Google backend)?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have a Django app with a standard `django.contrib.auth` backend and have a lot of existing users, now I want to add login via Google account using Python Social Auth. Is there any way to allow login via Google account for existing users? How should I associate it with existing users?

Is it okey to set up `'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email'` ?

So when user try to log in using Google account and already have an account (created using standard registration with password) in my app then will be automatically logged in. I don't want to allow creating new accounts using Python Social Auth, only allow to login via Google for existing users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Cox, you can use this pipeline but pay attention because according to the django doc :

> This pipeline entry is not 100% secure unless you know that the
> providers enabled enforce email verification on their side, otherwise
> a user can attempt to take over another user account by using the same
> (not validated) email address on some provider.